# How do I run the tcl proc function with verilog?

Tags: tcl, verilog

currently I've got some bunch of tcl files. in the tcl files, especially in the one tcl, I found the below a proc function in the tcl.

```
proc ahb_write {addr data {str s}} {
    set    ahbm top.cpu_subsys                      
    ...

    if {$::verbose  > 0} {
    }
    silent {
           ...........
           ...........
            delay 1
```

So I want to invoke and run this ahb_write proc function when I run the simulation.

Is there any possible way to run the proc function when I run the simulation with verilog?

Comment: most simulators have tcl based shell, don't know what you're using, but most likely the simulator is the target to your proc and not the verilog. take a look at the GUI and look for the place where the transcript is written - usually this is where you can add your text.

Comment: @user2141046 thanks BTW, can you let me know any example about how to run the simulation at the ncverilog or irun with proc tcl?

Comment: Sorry, I only had a chance of using Modelsim and slight VNC before leaving the area. Both of them used tcl interfaces - and we're talking two of the biggest companies in the field (Mentor and Synopsys).

Comment: May this PDFbe helpful. http://verificationhorizons.verificationacademy.com/volume-7_issue-3/articles/stream/using-scripting-language-in-combination-with-the-verification-testbench_vh-v7-i3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the SystemVerilog DPI to do this in any simulator. In Modelsim, you would call the function `mti_fli::mti_com("command")` An alternative that would probably work in any simulator is to to have a command executed upon hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: sorry  our company just got cadence's ncverilog and simvision. can you let me know by using cadence?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before where I wanted to use a verilog task that would inject bit errors on a memory.  In NCSim, I had to first individually deposit the values for the parameters of the task and then call the task itself.

```
deposit tinst.u_buffer.u_fifo.u_sram_0.injectSA.addr 1
deposit tinst.u_buffer.u_fifo.u_sram_0.injectSA.bitn 2
deposit tinst.u_buffer.u_fifo.u_sram_0.injectSA.typen 1
task    tinst.u_buffer.u_fifo.u_sram_0.injectSA
run 0.1
```

I don't know for sure if the 'run 0.1' was necessary or not, but I know this at least worked in my example.

The verilog task was defined in the RAM model like this:

```
task injectSA;
input [numWordAddr-1:0] addr;
input integer bitn;
input typen;
...
```